# The system is running in low-graphics mode in Ubuntu 14.04 and /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf missing

Tags: 14.04, graphics, lightdm

I always see the low-graphics mode error and have tried several solutions (links below) but in vain. [intel graphics, Ubuntu 14.04 running on a dual boot with windows7]

[How to fix "The system is running in low-graphics mode" error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error)

[How to fix "The system is running in low-graphics mode" error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error)

And finally to try this http://linuxg.net/fix-error-the-system-is-runnig-in-low-graphic-mode/   i don't see the lightdm.conf file.

I tried to reinstall lightdm and when I do it I don't find the file /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf. Its just not there at all.

The logs: [/var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8809217/) and [/var/log/lightdm/x-0-greeter.log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8809227/)

Comment: `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` is no longer used by default. Most of the configuration is in `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d`. Can you post `/var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log`, `/var/log/lightdm/x-*-greeter.log`? Use http://paste.ubuntu.com if the logs are too long.

Comment: Here are the links with logs  http://paste.ubuntu.com/8809217/  http://paste.ubuntu.com/8809227/

Comment: please in the future edit your question to provide relevant information. You should remove the comment now.

Answer (score 1):

The Unity greeter is not starting up. From `/var/log/x-0-greeter.log`:

```
/usr/sbin/unity-greeter: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libido3-0.1.so.0: undefined symbol: ubuntu_menu_item_factory_get_type
```

You could try with another greeter, or another Display Manager. For the first option, try:

```
sudo apt-get install lightdm-gtk-greeter
```

Just installing it should set it as the default. You can force it to be the default:

```
sudo tee /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/99-gtk-greeter.conf <<EOF
[SeatDefaults]
greeter-session=lightdm-greeter
EOF
sudo service lightdm restart
```

This should let LightDM start up if the problem is solely with the Unity greeter.

Installing GTK3 and GLib from source will cause problems, since Ubuntu applies patches to them ([here's a similar instance](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2097359&page=49) where a patch wasn't applied in a PPA). If you wish to install higher versions of these, look for PPAs, like the GNOME3 PPAs ([Main](https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/ubuntu/gnome3), [staging](https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/ubuntu/gnome3-staging)).

Comment: the lightdm fails to startup. and i dont ding the file 99-gtk-greeter.conf and instead i have 60-lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf. I added the lines and still lightdm doesnt start.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/8809480/    http://paste.ubuntu.com/8809497/

Comment: Nope. Still the same error. http://paste.ubuntu.com/8809560/  http://paste.ubuntu.com/8809569/      Just yesterday I have installed gtk3.12.2 and glib2.42.0 to install wireshark from sources. I made a shutdown and start again then met with this problem. Now I have both gtk2 and gtk3 installed on mine. Should this be a problem with this.

Comment: @user2729084 I'd be pretty certain that's the cause. Did you install those to `/usr/local/` or to `/usr/`? Did you use `checkinstall`?

Comment: I used default installation. ./configure make and make install. So should I uninstall the gtk3.12.2?  All the gtk3 files are installed to /usr/local/lib  and i see both gtk2 and gtk3 in /etc

Comment: Try reinstalling gtk3 and glib2 first: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgtk-3{-common,-bin,} libglib2.0-{bin,data,0}` (There's a trailing comma with the gtk3 packages.)

Comment: previously i installed both of them via sources. Should I uninstall via sources and reinstall via apt-get.?

Comment: Uninstalling gtk3 SOlved the problem. Thanks for your support.

Comment: When I tried to change to unity greeter: I have installed lightdm-gtk-greeter and it presents the login screen, where I enter password and enter: the screen is blank for 2-3 seconds and it loads the same login page. This repeats.

here are the logs of /var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log http://paste.ubuntu.com/8816878/
/var/log/lightdm/x-0-greeter.log http://paste.ubuntu.com/8816910/

Now I am trying to shift to unity greeter and not able to do that. Please provide your support

Comment: stuck with this problem now- http://askubuntu.com/questions/545776/lightdm-gtk-greeter-keeps-loping-into-login-screen   can you please take a look into it

Comment: @user2729084 did you reinstall gtk3 and glib, by the way?