# lightdm-gtk-greeter keeps loping into login screen

Tags: 14.04, lightdm, login-screen, gtk

Since I had problems with unity-greeter I had installed lightdm-gtk-greeter and it keeps looping into the login screen. 14.04 ubuntu

I have several solutions: removing .Xauthority file, reinstalling lightdm-gtk-greeter, ubuntu-desktop but no success. 
When I remove the .Xauthority file and do lightdm restart the .Xauthority file is created again.

Here are the log files from /var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log and /var/log/lightdm/x-0-greeter.log

http://paste.ubuntu.com/8826033/
http://paste.ubuntu.com/8826044/

Please need your help to login.

Comment: Can you please post the contents of `~/.xsession-errors` also?

Comment: Here it is: http://paste.ubuntu.com/8826374/

Comment: And the contents of `~/.xinputrc`, since `.xsession-errors` says there's an error in that file.

Comment: here is .xinputrc http://paste.ubuntu.com/8826426/

Comment: Then delete `~/.xinputrc`.

Comment: It worked. Is it safe to use unity-greeter now.

Comment: Absolutely. ~/.xinputrc is used by im-config, but if it's not there, the input method is set to default (ibus) via other files. If you open gnome-language-selector it will be re-created in a correct manner.

Comment: gnome-language selector displays in german lanugage. how can change it to english. I am using a german keyboard.

Comment: Please see [the documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/session-language.html) on that.

Comment: @guntbert: Done.

Answer (score 2):

Contents of `~/.xsession-errors`:

```
Script for ibus started at run_im.
Script for auto started at run_im.
Script for default started at run_im.
/usr/sbin/lightdm-session: 5:/home/altaf/.xinputrc: Syntax error: newline unexpected
```

It shows us that the problem is caused by a syntax error in the file `~/.xinputrc`. That file was created by *im-config*, but has apparently been edited accidentally. Rather than trying to fix the syntax error, it's easiest to simply delete `~/.xinputrc`. It will be re-created when needed.